# StramBuilder not working , with no errors. FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

hey guys **I'm new to Flutter**, and I'm turning to build a very simple chat app for learning purposes, I'm using StreamBulider for that, **it shows me no errors**, but it's not working

**I tread to add Text** Widget on its own without the streambuilder so I can make sure that the problem with the streambulder function not anything else and it's works fine

can anyone help find what went wrong?

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'chat_screen';
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}
 
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String messegeText;
  late User loogedInUser;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GetCurrentUser Method...
 
  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      // ignore: await_only_futures
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loogedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get Masseges Method...
 
  void messegesStream() async {
    await for (var snapshot in _fireStore.collection('messeges').snapshots()) {
      for (var message in snapshot.docs) {
        print(message.data());
      }
    }
  }
 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Code Start...
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.download),
              onPressed: () {
                messegesStream();
                // _auth.signOut();
                // Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: const Text('⚡️Chat'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
//------------------------------------------------------------
// StreamBuilder method...
 
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
 
                    for (var message in messages) {
                      final messageText = message.get('text');
                      final messageSender = message.get('sender');
                      final messageWidget =
                          Text('$messageSender said $messageText');
                      messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                    }
                  }
                  return Column(
                    children: messageWidgets,
                  );
                },
              ),
//------------------------------------------------------------
              Container(
                decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          messegeText = value;
                        },
                        decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                      ),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _fireStore.collection('messeges').add(
                          {
                            'text': messegeText,
                            'sender': loogedInUser.email,
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Send',
                        style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my android emulator screen,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> chatSnapshot) {
            if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(),
              );
            }
            return ListView(
              reverse: true,
              controller: _controller,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              children:
              chatSnapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return Text(data["text"]);
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: sorry @DO_Xuan _Thuc its not working